# using vlc to concatenate videos

Tags: video, vlc-media-player

I tried this command to join two videos that are of the same resolution and fps

```
"C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" 1.mp4 2.mp4 --sout "#gather​:std{access=file,dst=src.mp4}" --sout-keep
```

all it did was generate an empty mp4. what is the mistake here?